# How to make check a checkbox by clicking on the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

As the title says, I am trying to click on a div containing a checkbox and check/uncheck it using only the parent element.

this is the jsfiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/asbd4hpr/70/

and the codes.

html

```
<div class="js-form-item">
    <input class="solution-subtype-checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="solution-subtype-checkboxes" value="">
    <label for="edit-tpe-option-a-checkboxes-accs-au-module-note-de-frais" class="option">checkbox label</label>
</div>
```

css:

```
.js-form-item{
  border:1px solid red; 
  padding:50px; 
  max-width:100px; 
  max-height:100px; 
}
```

But I am not sure if this is avaiable

Comment: Do you plan to use Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work from the label **IF the** `for` attribute **was pointing to the right** `id` **input** .

then a pseudo + position:relative/absolute will let you cover the all area .

```css
.js-form-item{
  border:1px solid red; 
  padding:50px; 
  max-width:100px; 
  max-height:100px; 
  position:relative;/* make it reference for absolute children */
}

.js-form-item label:before {
  position:absolute;/* being part of the label,lets stick it and let it catch the pointer-events */
  content:'';/*make it be */
  /* size it to cover the closest relative(or absolute/fixed) parent */
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item">
  <input class="solution-subtype-checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="solution-subtype-checkboxes" name="" value="">
  <label for="solution-subtype-checkboxes" data-id="edit-tpe-option-a-checkboxes-accs-au-module-note-de-frais" class="option">checkbox label</label>
</div>
```

I updated the for attribute and send its old value to a data attribute to allow use it from javascript or CSS.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/asbd4hpr/70/

Answer (score 4):

I'd just convert the `div.js-form-item` into the `label` for the checkbox (and likewise convert the inner `label` to a `span`.) You'll also have to make the `label` a block element.

```css
.js-form-item{
  display: block;
  border:1px solid red; 
  padding:50px; 
  max-width:100px; 
  max-height:100px; 
}
```

```html
<label class="js-form-item">
 <input class="solution-subtype-checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="solution-subtype-checkboxes" value="">
 <span for="edit-tpe-option-a-checkboxes-accs-au-module-note-de-frais" class="option">checkbox label</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/asbd4hpr/72/

```js
clickedOn = function() {
 var val = document.getElementById('solution-subtype-checkboxes').checked;
  document.getElementById('solution-subtype-checkboxes').checked = !val;
}
```

```css
.js-form-item{
  border:1px solid red; 
  padding:50px; 
  max-width:100px; 
  max-height:100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="js-form-item" onclick="clickedOn();">
 <input class="solution-subtype-checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="solution-subtype-checkboxes" value="">
 <label for="edit-tpe-option-a-checkboxes-accs-au-module-note-de-frais" class="option">checkbox label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: why not using click() method  `$('js-form-item:has(input[type=checkbox])').click(function (event) {
        if(event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').click();
        }
    });`